# Shell script to convert unix timestamp filename of each file to regular date/time

Tags: shell

I have a directory that contains a bunch of files with the following format:

.tar.gz

and I would like to convert all of them with a simple shell script and have the following format:

YY_MM_DD_H_M_S.tar.gz

I know that this would be achieved with a date -d @ in order to find the exact date of that timestamp, and it should be included within a greater do-while but I don't know how to substitute the actual filename (and be applied to all the files in that directory).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is the date (new name of file) is coming from? is it the last modification date?

Comment: Hi Yossi, in fact I want the dates that are actually stamped on the files (recorded) not the day they were last modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I played around a bit and got into this solution - might not be elegant, but it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir newfiles
for f in *.tar.gz
do

 ustamp=$(echo "$f" | rev | cut -d"." -f3-  | rev)

 TIME=$(date -d @"$ustamp" '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
 cp $f newfiles/$TIME.tar.gz
 rm "$f";
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $ x=$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S)
 $ rename .tar.gz _${x}.tar.gz *.tar.gz
```

This will rename following files:

```
a.tar.gz
ez.tar.gz
```

to

```
a_2018_01_28_02_16_36.tar.gz
ez_2018_01_28_02_16_36.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, I need for each unix timestamp on each filename to get the actual value of the timestamp (i.e. the actual date that the file was recorded).  So, for each file the date command should get the actual value ( something along the lines of "date -d @<timestamp>") and the actual results should be the new filename every turn